# Spring Boot 2 + Spring Security + Login Form + Session Redis not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I'm trying to use `Spring Boot 2 + Spring Security + Session Redis` but for some reason after login the page is redirect to `/` but got access denied then page is back to login, anyone knows how to solve that please?

Following piece of code.

**Security Config**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(WHITELIST).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout();
}
```

**Spring Boot Config**

```
spring:
    application:
        name: eureka-server
    session:
        store-type: redis
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2019-09-29 18:43:23.578  INFO 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

2019-09-30 21:27:15.053 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-09-30T20:27:15.051Z, principal=admin@gmail.com, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null}]
2019-09-30 21:27:15.054 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@4910afdf
2019-09-30 21:27:15.055 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-30 21:27:15.055 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4893c999: Principal: Authentication(id=5d8d299d42eba40001932c0f, email=admin@gmail.com, password={bcrypt}$2a$10$DNbJo.ktPvjiVbsZdKEmDeC27R3y4RW/XZ1WsCSjPNmEmIf9JozNi, fullName=Admin dos Santos, enabled=true, authorities=[Authority(role=ROLE_ADMIN)]); Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: Authority(role=ROLE_ADMIN)
2019-09-30 21:27:15.057 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-30 21:27:15.057 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] RequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler : Using default Url: /
2019-09-30 21:27:15.057 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to '/'
2019-09-30 21:27:15.057 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2f60713f
2019-09-30 21:27:15.058 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-30 21:27:15.058 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
2019-09-30 21:27:15.058 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-30 21:27:15.058 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-30 21:27:15.059 DEBUG 28916 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : A new session was created. To help you troubleshoot where the session was created we provided a StackTrace (this is not an error). You can prevent this from appearing by disabling DEBUG logging for org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/':

org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@fc73db7

servletPath:/
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8761
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
referer: http://localhost:8761/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-IE,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
cookie: io=udDSi_WRWSnc1P5rAAAB; JSESSIONID=711725AFFC0C8C60E5A099A72EF2F420


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
2019-09-29 18:43:23.579 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.579 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.580 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-29 18:43:23.581 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2019-09-29 18:43:23.582 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@8360265a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.583 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/eureka/apps/**'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/actuator/**'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/v1/agent/self'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/eureka/peerreplication/batch/**'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/v1/catalog/services'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/v1/catalog/service/**'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/*.js'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/*.css'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/*.html'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/favicon.ico'
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.584 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@8360265a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2019-09-29 18:43:23.586 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5a1e2d1b, returned: -1
2019-09-29 18:43:23.587 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-09-29T17:43:23.586Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2019-09-29 18:43:23.588 DEBUG 29922 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried to follow example of documentation but got same issue - https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html

PS: Using Docker

Comment: Judging from the logging you aren't authenticated, looking at it you are still anonymous.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I added extra log showing the user is authenticated right but after redirect to / invalidate the session and create another anonymous.

Comment: I doubt it invalidates the session but rather doesn't send either the session cookie or header you are using.

Comment: It's very strange if I remove `spring-session-data-redis` on the classpath everything works fine, it might be some silly configuration that I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Find out which solution you use for obtaining the session-id. This can be cookie, header or something else. If you are using a cookie and don't send it you have no session, the same for the request header if there is no session identifier no session will be retrieved. I suspect that something like that is happening? Or maybe the cookie written isn't fully correct for the URL  you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the issue adding a Custom `CookieSerializer`.

```
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("SESSIONID");
    serializer.setCookiePath("/");
    serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
    return serializer;
}
```